# Deserialize Json Object with for each

Tags: c#, json

```
        var serverData = serverConnection.connect("login.php", pairs);

        RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await serverData);

        foreach (Logined m in json.logined)
        {

        }


        public class Logined
        {

            public string id { get; set; }
            public string firsname { get; set; }
            public string lastname { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone { get; set; }
            public string profilePic { get; set; }
            public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Logined logined { get; set; }
        }
```

the error in the for each it says cannot operate on variables of type public definition for getenumerator

Comment: There is no collection here to enumerate.  Maybe RootObject.logined should be an array?

Comment: Can you tell us where do you have collection of objects?  Right now you don't have any, however looks like you expect to have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root object contains only a single Logined, so there is nothing to enumerate.

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Logined logined { get; set; } //not a collection
    }

    foreach (Logined m in json.logined) //json.logined is a single object (not a collection)
    {

    }
```

If your server is returning a collection of Logined, you have to change your RootObject definition.

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public Logined[] logined { get; set; } //array of Logined
    }
```